# Wait for process to open in form load event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to wait for a process to be running before I exit my **Form Load event**.

The idea is loading my form with a label like "Waiting for process to launch..."

Then when I detect that the process is running, just exit the loop.

This is the code I'm using but it's blocking the form, **when I run my form it just won't show up but will keep running that while loop.**

```
Process[] procs = { };

while (procs.Length == 0)
{
    procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("otclient.exe"));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: You can `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(100);` doesn't seem like load is a good place for that though

Comment: probably you should 1) use the [Form.Shown event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) event and 2) you should shove this waiting loop into an async method and await it, this way the GUI won't freeze

Comment: You could have also just used a standard Timer and checked for the existence of the process in the Tick() event...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic idea using the [Form.Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) event and an async method:

```
private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelWaiting.Text = "Waiting for process to launch...";
    await WaitForProcessToLaunch("otclient.exe");
    labelWaiting.Text = "Done";
}

private async Task WaitForProcessToLaunch(string processName)
{
    Process[] procs = { };
    while (procs.Length == 0)
    {
        procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName));
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

After the form is loaded and visible it will immediately start the waiting procedure. The async shown event will prevent the GUI from freezing.

Comment: How does the appearance of the process trigger an event to set `stopWaiting = true;`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited the post to make it a little more clearer. Did it get clearer?

Comment: Yes, but the OP is waiting for a process to appear. That's not the same as a click. What is the event that triggers `stopWaiting = true;`?

Comment: OK, so based on the latest edit, what is the point of the `buttonStopWaiting_Click` method?

Comment: @Enigmativity that is a relict from my testing. You are right. I changed it into a more fitting answer without any confusing detours